# Looking for a Q&D PHP SQLite editing solution

Tags: php, open-source, admin

Here's what I need: I have a table in a SQLite file, that contains items - descriptions, dimensions, image and thumbnail.

I need to allow someone from outside the company to edit this table through an "admin interface". I need a simple login mechanism to authenticate said user, and I need a form that shows all available rows in the table applicable to him/her, and allow editing the values. That may include uploading images.

Now, I've developed tons of these interfaces before, in several languages. What I'd like to ask is: is there a shortcut? Since this needs to be quick and dirty (i.e., this wasn't in the original plan, I'm not being paid for this, but I may lose a client if I don't have it in place) and be up as soon as possible, is there some open source solution, or any previous PHP code, that I can customize and use in this and future cases?

Any solution that will save me time is welcome.

Thanks for YOUR time :)
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you can use a framework you could use an auto generated admin interface or scaffolding from a framework. Symfony and Cake both have this. Of course thats a lot of dead weight to have if the whole app/site isnt using the framework. But it would make it relatively painless to create. IF you can run this interface on a subdomain that would make it even esier since you dont have to worry about integrating it with anything existing except the DB and shared folder for the uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been considering Cake. Never used Symfony before. Is it wort the effort? Would you use a framework, or just burn some hours writing it from scratch?

Comment: I like Symfony.. about 70% of the work i do is Symfony 1.4 based. I use Cake a couple times because it was already being use don projects i came into late in the process. Personally i didnt enjoy it. That said there is a lot to lean with Symfony so it might not be the best route at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Looks like I'll give Cake a 10 minute brush, and if I don't see what I need immediately, it's down to the code.